# How to append row in table body using script

Tags: jquery, html, json

From the json data I'm trying to display values in table of html but it fails to do the same. I'm not able to recognize the error.I've used in the following way but I can't find the answer:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Check</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getRow(begin,phrase,buggy,words,negative,comma,loos,leng) {


jQuery('#donut').empty();

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var nb = begin;
var bp = phrase;
var bw = buggy;
var uw = words;
var nt = negative;
var punc = comma;
var loose = loos;
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut',
  data: [
    {value: nb, label: 'Should not begin'},
    {value: bp, label: 'Buggy phrase'},
    {value: bw, label: 'Buggy word'},
    {value: uw, label: 'Useless word'},
    {value: nt, label: 'Negative term'},
    {value: punc, label: 'Punctuation mistake'},
    {value: loose, label: 'Loose sentence'},
    {value: 0, label: 'Tense'}
  ],
  formatter: function (x) { return x + "%"}
}).on('click', function(i, row){
  console.log(i, row);
});
});
} 
</script>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var tab1 = "";
var posts = [{"begin": 0, "loose": 1, "leng": 8, "buggy": 0, "negative": 1, "nam": "10.Conclusion and future ", "comma": 5, "words": 1, "date": "2017-04-03 16:08:40", "phrase": 0}, {"begin": 0, "loose": 1, "leng": 11, "buggy": 5, "negative": 1, "nam": "8.Chapter 5.docx", "comma": 5, "words": 0, "date": "2017-04-03 16:06:49", "phrase": 0}, {"begin": 10, "loose": 6, "leng": 280, "buggy": 16, "negative": 12, "nam": "7.Chapter 4.docx", "comma": 194, "words": 2, "date": "2017-04-03 12:11:23", "phrase": 0}, {"begin": 1, "loose": 2, "leng": 20, "buggy": 5, "negative": 6, "nam": "eunoia", "comma": 4, "words": 3, "date": "2016-12-20 12:33:40", "phrase": 4}];


jQuery(posts).each(function(i,f){
alert(f.leng);
   var dt = f.date.split(" ");
   var tblRow = "<tr role=\"row\">" + "<td onclick=\"getRow(" +f.begin,f.phrase,f.buggy,f.words,f.negative,f.comma,f.loose,f.leng+")\">" + f.nam +"<td>" + dt[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + dt[1] + "</td>" + "</tr>";
       tab1 += tblRow;


     });     
            jQuery(tab1).appendTo("#example tbody");

});
</script>
</head>


<body>

            <table id="example" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black">
                <thead>
                    <tr role="row">
                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 150px;">File Name</th>
                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 109px;">Date</th>
                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 82px;">Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

From the json data I'm trying to display values in table of html but it fails to do the same. I'm not able to recognize the error.

Comment: `posts[i].leng` may be an issue - assuming you're trying to get the number of items in the array it should be `length`. You're also doing a lot of unnecessary string concatenation, eg. `"<tr class=\"odd\" role=\"row\">" + "<td onclick=`. You could also delimit the string with `'` to prevent the need to escape the inner `"`

Comment: can you add the html code.

Comment: What did you get? how it is not working?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and proper problem description

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Before posting it here I've tried all that but its not displaying the element

Comment: @chsdk table value is not displaying

Comment: @charlietfl I'll try to elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in  I should have written as

> "td onclick= \"getRow("+f.begin+","+f.phrase+","+f.buggy+","+f.words+","+f.negative+","+f.comma+","+f.loose+","+f.leng+")\">

here , should also be trated as string.

Answer (score -1):

You can append table row like below,

```
function table_element(posts) {
for (i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {        
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    var t1= "<tr class=\"even\" role=\"row\">" + "<td onclick=\"getRow("  + posts[i].begin, posts[i].leng + ")\" >" + "</td>" + "<td class=\"\">" + posts[i].nam + "</td>" + "<td class=\"\">" + posts[i].words + "</td>" + "<td class=\"sorting_1\">" + posts[i].date.split(" ")[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + posts[i].date.split(" ")[1] + "</td>" + "</tr>"
    $("#example1").append(t1);
  } else {
    var t2 = "<tr class=\"odd\" role=\"row\">"+"<td onclick=\"getRow("+posts[i].begin, posts[i].leng+")\">"+"</td>"+"<td class=\"\">" +posts[i].nam+"</td>"+"<td class=\"\">" +posts[i].words+"</td>"+"<td class=\"sorting_1\">" +posts[i].date.split(" ")[0]+"</td>"+"<td>"+posts[i].date.split(" ")[1]+"</td>"+"</tr>"
    $("#example1").append(t2);
 }
 }   
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, thanks for your explanation. He asked how to append a row, so only i have modified the code and gave

Comment: All you seem to have changed is `appendTo()` to `append()`. If the former doesn't work, I don't see why the latter would